# My asp:gridview can't show object from IQueryable result

Tags: asp.net, .net, entity-framework, gridview, dbcontext

scenario:

```
         platform: Visual studio 2012,

         framework: .net framework 4.5
```

Problem:

I am having a problem with my asp:GridView. When I try to bring the data from a IQueryable result only primitive types are returning. The primitive types are showing in the gridview, but not object SpecieModel and ObjectRole from CitizenModel.

Any ideas about what can be happening?

I have CitizenModel class below

```
[Browsable(false)]
    [Key]
    public int Id { get; set; }

    [Browsable(true)]
    [Required(ErrorMessage = "The name field is required")]
    public string Name { get; set; }

    [Browsable(true)]
    [Required(ErrorMessage = "The specie field is required")]
    public SpecieModel SpecieType { get; set; }

    [Browsable(true)]
    public RoleModel ObjectRole { get; set; }

    [NotMapped]
    public int Specie
    {
        get
        {
            if (this.SpecieType != null)
                return this.SpecieType.Id;
            else
                return 0;
        }
    }

    [NotMapped]
    public int Role
    {
        get
        {
            if (this.ObjectRole != null)
                return this.SpecieType.Id;
            else
                return 0;
        }
    }
```

My Context

```
public class ImperialDBContext :DbContext
{
    public ImperialDBContext()
        : base("DBImperial11")
    {
    }

    //protected override void OnModelCreating(DbModelBuilder modelBuilder)
    //{
    //    // other code 
    //    Database.SetInitializer<ImperialDBContext>(null);
    //    // more code
    //}

    public DbSet<CitizenModel> Citizens { get; set; }

    public DbSet<RoleModel> Roles { get; set; }

    public DbSet<LogErroModel> LogErros { get; set; }
```

}

My asp gridview:

```
<asp:GridView ID="gridDados" runat="server" ItemType="Imperial.Class.Entidade.CitizenModel" SelectMethod="CarregarGrid" DataKeyNames="Id" OnRowCommand="gridDados_RowCommand">
    <Columns>
        <asp:TemplateField ShowHeader="false">
            <ItemTemplate>
                <asp:LinkButton ID="LinkButton1" runat="server" CausesValidation="False" CommandName="Excluir" OnClientClick="return confirm('Deseja excluir ?')" CommandArgument='<%#: Item.Id %>' Text="Excluir"></asp:LinkButton>
            </ItemTemplate>
        </asp:TemplateField>
        <asp:TemplateField ShowHeader="false">
            <ItemTemplate>
                <asp:LinkButton ID="LinkButton2" runat="server" CausesValidation="False" CommandName="Editar" CommandArgument='<%#: Item.Id %>' Text="Editar"></asp:LinkButton>
            </ItemTemplate>
        </asp:TemplateField>

    </Columns>
</asp:GridView>
```

My method carregarGrid from gridview

```
public IQueryable<CitizenModel> CarregarGrid()
    {
        try
        {
            return ImperialFacade.Instancia.LoadCitizenDatas();
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            ImperialFacade.Instancia.InserirLogErro(new LogErroModel(ex.Message));
            throw ex;
        }
    }
```

In my Facade:

```
public IQueryable<CitizenModel> LoadCitizenDatas()
    {
        try
        {
            return new CitizenNegocio().LoadDatas();
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            throw new Exception(ex.Message);
        }
    }
```

Comment: How is LoadCitizenDatas implemented?

Comment: I edited the post with the implementation of LoadCitizenDatas.

Comment: Does it show Role and Specie properties?

Comment: No, only the primitive properties Id and Name